# regex to cut string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm new with python and I'm not good enough with Regular expression,

I have this text :

```
4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02cbc5
```

I want to cut this string using regex like that :

```
4c00 // the first 4 characters
0215 // the 4 second characters
023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9 // after the 32 characters
ffff // after the 4 characters
02cb // also the 4 characters
c5 // and finally the last two characters
```

I cut the string like this but I don't like the way:

```
        companyId = advData[10:14]
        advIndicator = advData[14:18]
        proximityUUID = advData[18:50]
        major = int(advData[50:54], 16)
        minor = int(advData[54:58], 16)
        signalPower = int(advData[-2:], 16)
```

Comment: What rule is this cutting following? I can't see any logic to it. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there any intention in your mind to get exactly the same output? Does these numbers show any specific thing or you just chose it? These should be some way to identify the pattern for getting output.

Comment: I Updated my question

Comment: regex does not seem applicable to this problem at all

Comment: why you don't use `slice` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s="0201041aff4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02cbc5"
print(re.findall("^(.{10})(.{8})(.{32})(.{4})(.{4})(.{2})",s))
```

but regex does not seem to be a good solution to this problem to me ... just use string slicing if you just want to take the next n characters

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nice solution

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem for regex. This is a solution:

```
text = '0201041aff4c000215023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9ffff02cbc5'

def split_at(s, index):
    return s[:index], s[index:]

res = []
for index in (10, 8, 32, 4, 4, 2):
    first, text = split_at(text, index)
    res.append(first)

print('\n'.join(res))
```

*outputs:*

```
0201041aff
4c000215
023f3d601143013582ba2e1e1603bcb9
ffff
02cb
c5
```

Comment: good job showing him a way that makes more sense than regex for this problem :) +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley Although I do kinda like the regex solution in a way :)

Comment: lol it might be a tiny bit "prettier" but it is not the right solution to this problem imho

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah I did consider the `iter(text)` solution but I thought I'd keep it simple(ish)

Comment: `["".join(islice(iterx,0,n)) for n in [10,8,32,4,4,2]]` :P

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Regex definitely isn't prettier.

Answer (score -2):

If the number of characters in each group never changes, you could use this:

(.{10})(.{8})(.{32})(.{4})(.{4})(.{2})